# gmaps4rails Float rounding numbers with MySQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

i haved a app with gmaps4rails running in development. The last week i upload to production with MySQL DB. All work cool but, searching address, i try to edit some longitude and latitude values and see the numbers appears rounded when i try to edit some location.

I want to know if i can do something like height or precision in float values? Or if is possible work with decimals in this two fields with gmaps4rails? and how can i move the values i have right now in float to the decimal values?

Thank you for you attention.

Comment: You may have an incorrect column type (int instead of decimal). please run this in your Rails console and paste the output in your question: `Map.columns.map{|col| "#{col.name} is #{col.sql_type}"}` (replace `Map` by the concerned model name)

Comment: @BenjaminSinclaire here is:     ["id is INTEGER", "category_id is integer", "name is varchar(255)", "warranty is boolean", "address is varchar(255)", "phone is varchar(255)", "schedule is varchar(255)", "email is varchar(255)", "web is varchar(255)", "about is text", "mision is text", "vision is text", "created_at is datetime", "updated_at is datetime", "city_id is integer", "latitude is float", "longitude is float", "gmaps is boolean"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You DB fiels are float, I am almost sure it need to be decimal in MySQL for it to work with gmaps4rails. You should perform a migration to modify your fields

**Very important:** if you have data you need to protect, you MUST do a full database dump before running the migration, I cannot guarantee you there is no risk to this operation.
As you have the situation in your prod server, additional to the DB dump I would advise to import the prod DB to your dev computer and test the migration here.

The rails migration should look like this:

```
change_column :my_table, :latitude, :decimal, precision: 10, scale: 8
change_column :my_table, :longitude, :decimal, precision: 11, scale: 8
```

Replace `my_table` by your table name, and adjust `precision` and `scale` as needed

Comment: i apply the new type, but the only problem right now, is the longitude convert numbers type: -116.988449 to -99.99999999. Any solution for this?

Comment: My apology, the precision was incorrect in my answer, I edited it